# Textbox to accept decimal and negative as well as backspace using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to restrict text box to accepts only decimals,integers and also - (negative sign) as well as backspace I tried with below script but its not allowing - sign

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#MainContent_txtAmount').keypress(function(event) {
    if ((event.which != 46 || $(this).val().indexOf('.') != -1) &&
      ((event.which < 48 || event.which > 57) &&
        (event.which != 0 && event.which != 8))) {
      event.preventDefault();
    }

    var text = $(this).val();
    if ((text.indexOf('.') != -1) &&
      (text.substring(text.indexOf('.')).length > 2) &&
      (event.which != 0 && event.which != 8) &&
      ($(this)[0].selectionStart >= text.length - 2)) {
      event.preventDefault();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="MainContent_txtAmount" type="text" />
```

How can I accepts negative numbers too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This allows the "-" sign too.   Added && event.which != 45 . [DEMO FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/anudeepr/yzggrtpo/)

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#MainContent_txtAmount').keypress(function (event) {
            if ((event.which != 46 || $(this).val().indexOf('.') != -1) &&
              ((event.which < 48 || event.which > 57) &&
                (event.which != 0 && event.which != 8)) && event.which != 45) {
                event.preventDefault();
            }

            var text = $(this).val();
            if ((text.indexOf('.') != -1) &&
              (text.substring(text.indexOf('.')).length > 2) &&
              (event.which != 0 && event.which != 8) &&
              ($(this)[0].selectionStart >= text.length - 2)) {
                event.preventDefault();
            }
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Find the attached fiddle

**<kbd>[sql fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bqskjg30/)</kbd>**

"-" has a charCode of 45.

change your condition `event.which < 48 || event.which > 57` to

```
event.which != 45 && (event.which < 48 || event.which > 57)
```